# How to run a "facebook app" on an IP (domain works, localhost works, IP does not)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

To do things with the Facebook API/SDK a developer can easily create an app account on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/. The developer needs to provide a real URL (www.example.com) for his/her project or `localhost`/`http://localhost` for local development.

#### Problem:

Applications are often developed on remote IP-based servers. But Facebook blocks IPs in the form, says IPs are "not valid". How to use the Facebook app creation form with an IP (or how to override this issue)?

To make clear what we are talking about: A screenshot of the form (it's in german, sorry).

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you need a domain and there is no way to make it work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a service of free Dynamic DNS like no-ip or DDNS to manage translating a domain (something.domain.com) to your public IP Address.

Comment: You have tried to use the IP? So you'll need to use the dinamic domain like I said.

Comment: @Panique this is the best approach for your problem. Give it some time to resolve the DNS and it will work. I go with the same approach as well